# How to sort 2 types of values for an array?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort the items in alphbatical order. However, I also want to sort item type as well.

For example:

I want

```
  type     sortValue

blockItem   a test1
blockItem   a test2
blockItem   b test3
imageItem   a image
imageItem   b image
imageItem   c image
imageItem   s image
textItem    a text
textItem    b text
textItem    c text
```

My code would do things like this.

```
  type     sortValue

blockItem   a test1
blockItem   a test2
imageItem   a image
textItem    a text
blockItem   b test3
imageItem   b image
textItem    b text
imageItem   c image
textItem    c text
imageItem   s image
```

my sort function

```
array contains type and sortvalue

array=array.sort(sortFunction);

function sortFunction(groupA, groupB) {

    if (groupA.sortValue > groupB.sortValue) {
        return 1;
    } else if (groupA.sortValue < groupB.sortValue) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It only sort the text but not the type. I was wondering if there are anyways to do this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the second key to compare if the first were equal:

```
function sortFunction(a, b) {
    if (a.key1 > b.key1) {
        return +1;
    } else if (a.key1 < b.key1) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a.key2 > b.key2) {
        return +1;
    } else if (a.key2 < b.key2) {
        return -1;
    } else 
    ...
    } else if (a.keyN > b.keyN) {
        return +1;
    } else if (a.keyN < b.keyN) {
        return -1;
    } else {
       return 0;
    }   
}
```

Or, for better readability:

```
function sortFunction(a, b) {
    if (a.key1 > b.key1) {
        return +1;
    } else if (a.key1 < b.key1) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a.key2 > b.key2) {
        return +1;
    } else if (a.key2 < b.key2) {
        return -1;
    }
    ...

    if (a.keyN > b.keyN) {
        return +1;
    } else if (a.keyN < b.keyN) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Btw, you can shorten it to `return (a.key1>b.key1)-(a.key1<b.key1) || (a.key2>b.key2)-(a.key2<b.key2) || … || (a.keyN>b.keyN)-(a.keyN b.keyN);`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (groupA.type == groupB.type) {
    /* your code */
}
else if (groupA.type > groupB.type) {
    return 1;
}
else if (groupA.type < groupB.type) {
    return -1;
}

return 0;
```